# How to cancel out an item with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a site responsive, and when it scales down, I want to cancel out the images. All my images are in HTML and I am trying to make them not show up as the screen scales down.

Comment: Add minimal html and css

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use media-queries.

**Example:**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .image-1 {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This will not display the image when the screen size (width) is smaller than 768px.

You can learn more about media-queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

CSS media queries are used for this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* anything here will have properties mentioned here
     if you want to hide all the images, use "img", else, use your specified class, such as .myImage */

   img {
    display: none;
   }
            /* OR */
   .images-to-hide {
    display: none;
   }

}
```

In `(max-width: 600px)`, you put the maximum screen width after which the styles stop working - or rather - the minimum value needed for these styles to be applied

Here's a more detailed tutorial: [W3Schools.com - Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)